# svn - review updates to "branch updated" files after merge?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging, svn-merge

I'm working on a feature branch in SVN and I'm trying to frequently bring in changes from the trunk so I don't get too out-of-date.

I've been using the command: `svn merge ^/parent/branch/path`

How do I get a clear list of the files that are both:

1. Files that the parent branch updated.
2. Files that I modiefied at some point since I made my branch.

The problem is that the working copy has ~3k source files.  My branch changes only cover ~50 files.

The merge command is bringing in many updates to files unrelated to my work.  This is OK.  I trust SVN can update those fine.

However, I do want to manualy review merges to files that I've worked on in my branch.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is of some help to you...

[SVN Mergeinfo and Preview](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo)